# Image gallery with no spaces

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a picture portfolio for myself, but have been running into some issues. I want to be able to post images with different aspect ratios, make them have the same width, and fit together perfectly on one page. As you can see in my example linked below, the first two rows look perfect, however when the aspect ratio of the images change in the second line, empty spaces begin to appear and the layout gets a bit messed up. Rather than empty white blocks forming as they do now, I would ideally want the images to snap together, so that they are all joined with no white space at all except left over space at the bottom of course.

Any suggestions on how this can be resolved would be greatly appreciated. I'd be willing to use Bootstrap if that's easier too. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know the code is not proper at all. It is just a quick sample I created.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 0px;
        }
        
        img {
            width: 33.33%;
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
    </style>    
</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/pBy6VTtwK5w/maxresdefault.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/IMG_0103.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Sequence-02.Still002.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/opuseg.png">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG_0011-768x456.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/1-e1458162436808-300x280.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG_0009-768x456.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://techunderstood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/IMG_1656.jpg">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a CSS tricks article covering this exact topic.

https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

**HTML:**

```
<section id="photos">
  <img src="images/cat-1.jpg" alt="Cute cat">
  <img src="images/cat-2.jpg" alt="Serious cat">
  ...
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved using the Masonry layout (Pinterest uses this layout to display the feed). I've used this library before and it worked as expected: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I noticed that it was not a smooth transition when change screen sizes. I used a different trick to do it just in CSS and it works perfectly. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I basically used this from CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/, except I changed the column count to what I wanted, and made custom breakpoints. Works perfectly :)